# PackageManager can't check for installed apps

Tags: android

I'm currently building an `app` that has `Facebook` and `Instagram` integration and I need to check whether the `app` has been installed on the user's `device` or not.

**I've tried out :**

```
private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri)
{
    PackageManager pm = fragment.getContext().getPackageManager();
    boolean app_installed = false;
    try
    {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        app_installed = true;
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        app_installed = false;
    }
    return app_installed ;
}
```

And I've passed in `"com.instagram.android"` and `"com.facebook.katana"` (Facebook) as the URI for the `package` name.

**My Code :**

```
binding.facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            boolean haveApp = appInstalledOrNot("com.facebook.katana");

            if (haveApp) {
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(SocialMediaSharingFragment.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "App not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

I've deleted the `Facebook` App from my `phone` and ran the code, but somehow I'm still getting a `true` returned from the `appInstalledOrNot` method.
Did the same for `Instagram` as well, still doesn't work. I'm using `DataBinding` as you can see and I'm using it on a `Fragment`, not an `Activity`.

Would really appreciate help on this.
Thanks for reading...

Comment: did your click multiple times after removing facebook ?

Comment: yes, many times

Comment: debug your code using the debugger.. !!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another flag:

```
pm.getPackageInfo(uri, 0);
```